# Custom logo button doesn't appear after adding theme support in functions.php Word Press

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm following tutorial to create custom theme for Word Press. I'm trying to add custom logo theme support but button doesn't appear in Word Press panel.

```
function fja_theme_support()
{
    add_theme_support('custom-logo');
}
add_action('after_theme_setup', 'fja_theme_support);
```

[here is my word press admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SOrN.png)

Comment: Your hook name should be `after_setup_theme` not `after_theme_support`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka it is, i miss spelled that here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example from Theme Developer Handbook

Hook should be named `after_setup_theme`, provide an array of additional settings - you can find them [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/)

```
function themename_custom_logo_setup() {
    $defaults = array(
        'height'               => 100,
        'width'                => 400,
        'flex-height'          => true,
        'flex-width'           => true,
        'header-text'          => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
        'unlink-homepage-logo' => true, 
    );
 
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
}
 
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themename_custom_logo_setup' );
```